# how to conform multiple protocols to a class and design methods to input and print details?

Tags: ios, swift, class, protocols

Design a protocol Student having data fields name, address, cgpa, course and semester. Create
another protocol SportsInfo having data fields fav_sports, weight and height. Now design Test class
which conforms Student protocol and SportsInfo protocol, design methods to input and print the details?

I have done Tried like this. But it's raising many errors near taking Input.

```
protocol Student{
    var name: String{get}
    var address: String{get}
    var cgpa: Double{get}
    var course: String{get}
    var semester: Int{get}
    
}
protocol SportsInfo{
    var fav_sports: String{get}
    var weight: Double{get}
    var height: Double{get}
}

class Test: Student,SportsInfo{
  var name = ""
  var address = ""
  var cgpa = 0.0  
  var course = ""
  var semester = 0
  var fav_sports = ""
  var weight = 0.0
  var height = 0.0
}


var a=Test()
func takeInputStudentInfo()
  {
    print("Enter your name:")
    a.name = readLine()!
    print("Enter your address:")
    a.address = readLine()!
    print("Enter your CGPA:")
    var b=readLine()
    a.cgpa = Double(b!)
    print("Enter the name of your Course")
    a.course = readLine()!
    print("Enter which semester are you in:")
    a.semester = Int(readLine())
  }
  
func takeInputSportsInfo(){
    print("Enter the name of your favorite Sport:")
    a.fav_sports = readLine()!
    print("Enter your Height:")
    a.weight = Double(readLine())
    print("Enter your Height:")
    a.height = Double(readLine())
  }
func printDetails(){
      print("Name: \(a.name)")
      print("Address: \(a.address)")
      print("CGPA: \(a.cgpa)")
      print("course: \(a.course)")
      print("semester: \(a.semester)")
      print("Fav Sport: \(a.fav_sports)")
      print("Weight: \(a.weight)")
      print("Height: \(a.height)")
  }
takeInputStudentInfo()  
takeInputSportsInfo()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `readline()` returns an Optional, and `Int(someString)` or `Double(someString)` also returns an Optional. But none of your properties that you want to assign to are Optionals. So you would need to unwrap twice to get the desired type.

You could do this with exclamation marks, but that, though it will compile, is likely to crash your program sooner or later:

```
var b=readLine()
a.cgpa = Double(b!)! // this compiles, but is it a good idea?
```

It would be better to learn about Optionals and how to unwrap them *safely*. You should form good linguistic and thought habits right from the start.

```
if let b = readLine() {
    if let d = Double(b) {
        a.cgpa = d
    }
}
```

A nice thing about this way of doing it is that `if` lets you say `else`. If you cannot derive a Double from what the user input, you can print a warning and loop again until you get a proper double. You'll want to write a utility routine that lets you do that. Here is how such a routine might go:

```
func getDoubleFromUser(_ message:String) -> Double {
    var result : Double?
    while result == nil {
        print(message)
        if let s = readLine(), let d = Double(s) {
            result = d
        }
    }
    return result!
}
func getIntFromUser(_ message:String) -> Int {
    var result : Int?
    while result == nil {
        print(message)
        if let s = readLine(), let i = Int(s) {
            result = i
        }
    }
    return result!
}
```

Now you can say

```
a.cgpa = getDoubleFromUser("Enter your CGPA:")
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

`readLine()` returns an optional value `String?`, but a `Double` initializer from a `String` requires it to be non-optional.

Furthermore, the `Double` initializer from a `String` returns an optional value `Double?` (because not all strings can be converted to a number), yet you're trying to assign it to a non-optional property.

You need to decide what to do when string cannot be converted to a number - do you just leave the default value, do you ask the user again?

Here's how you can unwrap the optional, and if it's `nil`, assign it some default value:

```
print("Enter your Height:")
a.height = Double( readLine() ?? "" ) ?? 0.0
```

Or leave whatever it was before

```
print("Enter your Height:")
if let inputString = readLine(), let height = Double(inputString) {
    a.height = height
}
```

You can also ask endlessly in a loop until you get the correct input that can be converted to a number, but I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader.